# Searching JSON array for values and accessing surrounding keys/values; output as JSON

Tags: php, json

I am having the hardest time trying to do something that I believe should be simple. I've read many examples regarding accessing PHP JSON arrays but I can't seem to find one to fit my use case (or I don't understand how the pieces fit).

Here is my JSON in PHP (example_data.php):

```
<?php
$contents = array(
    1 => array(
        'contentid' => '1',
        'full' => 'Song Name by Artist Name (maininfo)',
        'aname' => 'Artist Name',
        'sname' => 'Song Name',
        'main' => 'core content #1',
        'maininfo' => 'url'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'contentid' => '2',
        'full' => 'Song Name by Artist Name (maininfo)',
        'aname' => 'Artist Name',
        'sname' => 'Song Name',
        'main' => 'core content #2',
        'maininfo' => 'url')
    );
?>
```

The code below takes as input a search variable (`q`) and passes it along to search the JSON for partial or complete matches.

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

include('example_data.php');

$results = array('contents' => array());

foreach ($contents as $name => $data)
{
    if (stripos($name, $q) !== false)
    {
        $results['contents'][$name] = $data;
    }
}

$final_contents = array('header' => array(), 'data' => array());
$final_contents['header'] = array('title' => 'Music', 'num' =>  count($results['contents']), 'limit' => 6);


foreach ($results['contents'] as $name => $data)
{
    $final_contents['data'][] = array('primary' => $data['sname'], 'secondary' => $data['aname']);
}

/* Output JSON */
$final = array($final_contents);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($final);
die();
?>
```

It works fine but it will only search against the array name ('1' or '2' in this example) for a match.  Obviously users will not search for '1'--instead they will search for 'Artist Name' or 'Song Name' or the core content.

Would someone be so kind to tell me how I can modify this code to take 'q' and use it as a search against the 'full' key specifically -- if there is a partial/complete match in the value of 'full', I want to return it as JSON (including the aname, sname, main, maininfo, etc.). Multiple results are to be expected.  JSON is coming back now as expected but the user won't search for '1', '2', etc. so it is not really usable.

Really appreciate your time in advance!

Comment: You presumably want to match the content (values)? Your loop is comparing the numeric keys 1 and 2 to the search term, you need an extra loop. If you want to match the values rather than the keys you'll need to change the `stripos()` to `$data` instead of `$name` - example: https://eval.in/303046

Comment: This works really well @scrowler -- it seems to be matching on any value.  Can I limit it to only search against 'full' by chance?  Right now if you search for 'core' (for example), it is finding content within the 'main' key.  I would like it to only search one specific key ('full').   This is practically solved, thank you so much.

Comment: @scrowler - this is really good but with it matching on everything it is bringing back some things I don't want.  Is it possible to simply match on the value in the 'full' key.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, in that case you want to use `if (stripos($data['full'], $q) !== false)`

Comment: @scrowler - can you actually submit this as an answer?  This is PERFECT and is the closest to my original question.  There are some very nice answers provided by kurt below, however they are over engineered for my purpose.  **Thank you so much for your help**--can't believe how much time I spent on this and it was this simple.

Comment: You should post it as an answer yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine if there is a match and return the array in your outer loop

```js
$contents = array(
    1 => array(
        'contentid' => '1',
        'full' => 'Song Name by Artist Name (maininfo)',
        'aname' => 'Artist Name',
        'sname' => 'Song Name',
        'main' => 'core content #1',
        'maininfo' => 'url'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'contentid' => '2',
        'full' => 'Song Name by Artist Name (maininfo)',
        'aname' => 'Artist Name',
        'sname' => 'Song Name',
        'main' => 'core content #2',
        'maininfo' => 'url')
    );


$a = 'song'; // value that will be searched for in all fields
$percent = NULL;
$results = array();
$match = FALSE;
echo "starting search...<br>";
foreach($contents as $name) {

 foreach($name as $key =>$val){
 echo "starting full field match...<br>";
 if (isset($q) && similar_text($val,$a ,$percent )) {
    echo $name."[".$key."] = ".$val." vs ".$a." Percentage Match: ".$percent." % <br>";
   ($percent >40 ? $match = TRUE : $match = FALSE);
      if($match){
   echo "MATCHED % greater 40% match...<br>";
       break;
   }
   echo " end full field match<hr>";
    }
 
 
    if (isset($a) && similar_text($val,$a ,$percent )) {
 echo "starting name match...<br>";
       echo $name."[".$key."] = ".$val." vs ".$a." Percentage Match: ".$percent." % <br>";
   ($percent >40 ? $match = TRUE : $match = FALSE);
      if($match){
   echo "MATCHED % greater 40% match...<br>";
       break;
   }
    }
 echo " end name  match<hr>";
 }
    if ($match) {
 echo "Match added to array<br>";
      //push full array
      array_push($results, $name);
    }
   
  }
  echo "search completed<hr>";
  /* Output JSON */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results[0]);
die();
```

Comment: Can you modify this slightly?  Getting Undefined variable: final.  Thanks in advance for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.  Still getting an error:  Undefined offset: 0  -- this is when searching file.php?q=ArtistName --- note that I am looking for partial matches so if a artist name is Rick Smith, I would like it to hit on Rick as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: then use 'similar_text ( string $first , string $second [, float &$percent ] ) ' to generate your match it returns a match to a variable as a percentage. to check the index of the array for the undefined offest 'print_r(array) between two '<pre>' tags

Comment: Could you provide an example @kurt by chance?  I'm sorry--I don't understand this one.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, I went to bed. It needed an extra for loop, you can copy and paste my example as it and then modify it for get

Comment: I am still getting 'Undefined offset: 0' :( -- Can you explain why 'gnud' (for example) would ever land on a hit? I would start a chat but I don't have the rep yet. Sorry this is such a pain

Comment: gnud is an example for a missmatch, the hit is coming from $a = 'song'. Ill add some echos so you can see what the script is doing

Comment: Updated it, it will now echo what its doing. Copy and paste the example as is into a new file and run it. I also changed it so it searches a single value against all fields

Comment: you continue to be very helpful so thank you for your time!  What do I need to do to have this search ONLY the 'full' key? As you said, it is searching against all fields but the original request is for it to compare against only 'full' => '**need to search this**' --  Also, the code you gave me when copied and pasted and run with no changes has many 'Notice: Array to string conversion' messages.  Is there a way to suppress these assuming they are by design?  I will mark this answer as correct soon--I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Even though scrowler 's response was actually the most simple and exactly what I needed personally, I believe @kurt 's answer will suit most people and allow for greater flexibility.  Thank you to the both of you for helping me get this solved.   In the end, I simply changed one line from if (stripos($name, $q) !== false) to if (stripos($data['full'], $q) !== false).   Thank you very much guys!