# javascript / jquery Accessing JSON array by both name and index

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I am very much hoping you can help me with this as I've spent all too much time on this.  First, my JSON formatting is unfortunately not very mutable and I have moved it to a number of different formats to support both some jquery and a php-based search.  Each time I move it, the search will work and the rest of the site will break or vice-versa.

Is it possible to access a JSON array by both name and index number?  Here is my JSON (stored in PHP file and being retrieved & converted successfully to valid JSON):

```
<?php

$contents = array(
'Song Name #1 by Artist Name #1 (maininfo)' => array(
    'contentid' => '1',
    'aname' => 'Artist Name',
    'sname' => 'Song Name',
    'main' => 'core content #1',
    'maininfo' => 'url')
),
'Song Name #2 by Artist Name #2 (maininfo)' => array(
    'contentid' => '2',
    'aname' => 'Artist Name',
    'sname' => 'Song Name',
    'main' => 'core content #2',
    'maininfo' => 'url')
);

?>
```

My search works when something in the array title is matched on, otherwise it returns no matches so I must leave the array title as-is.

Another part of my project uses jquery and has the following:

```
parse(jsonobj[0][1]['sname']) //successfully already returning 'Song Name'
```

The above will ONLY work when the array title is not provided (e.g. **'Song Name #1 by Artist Name #1 (maininfo)' => array(** becomes simply **array(**.

For those curious, file is being converted to JSON using:

```
var jsonobj;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getjson.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (doc) {

        jsonobj = doc;

        }
  });
```

On the PHP side, when getjson.php is called the JSON array (above) is loaded in and converted to valid JSON using:

```
$final = array($final_contents);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($final);
```

Note: $final_contents is just $contents with an additional header added.  See [Searching JSON array for values and accessing surrounding keys/values; output as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200622/searching-json-array-for-values-and-accessing-surrounding-keys-values-output-as) for the PHP I have running specifically.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you also paste the code that is being used to pass $content to the jquery callback on success?

Comment: @AshutoshNigam - I believe I just added it to the original post.  Basically, the ajax json call is loading a file called getjson.php which grabs the JSON-style array I have in php and converts it to valid JSON.  See the link I added for a post I had yesterday with a different challenge--it contains the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes. You should encode it as a JSON object instead.

```
var $contents = {
    "Song Name #1 by Artist Name #1 (maininfo)": {
        "contentid": 1,
        "aname": "Artist Name",
        "sname": "Song Name",
        "main": "core content #1",
        "maininfo": "url"
    },{
    "Song Name #2 by Artist Name #2 (maininfo)": {
        "contentid": 2,
        "aname": "Artist Name",
        "sname": "Song Name",
        "main": "core content #2",
        "maininfo": "url"
    }
};
```

Although it would probably be better to arrange it this way (here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12pejo5o/) to demonstrate:

```
var songs = [
    {
        "contentid": 1,
        "artist": "Artist Name",
        "title": "Song Title 1",
        "main": "core content #1",
        "maininfo": "url"
    },
    {
        "contentid": 2,
        "artist": "Artist Name",
        "title": "Song Title 2",
        "main": "core content #2",
        "maininfo": "url"   
    }
];
```

Then you can search through your songs list by id, or iterate through to filter on specific field values. For instance to find all songs whose titles start with "Song Title":

```
var findAllSongs = function(prop, value){
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
        var song = songs[i];
        if (song[prop] && (song[prop] === value || song[prop].search(value) >= 0)){
            result.push(song);
        }
    }
    return result;
};

var song = findAllSongs("title","Song Title 2")[0];
alert(song.contentid);
// Outputs "2"
```

The php equivalent of my json above is:

```
$songs = array(
    array(
        "contentid" => 1,
        "artist" => "Artist Name",
        "title" => "Song Title 1",
        "main" => "core content #1",
        "maininfo" => "url",
    ),
    array(
        "contentid" => 2,
        "artist" => "Artist Name",
        "title" => "Song Title 2",
        "main" => "core content #2",
        "maininfo" => "url",    
    )
);
```

If you're using PHP 5.4 or higher, you can use the short syntax:

```
$songs = [
    [
        "contentid" => 1,
        "artist" => "Artist Name",
        "title" => "Song Title 1",
        "main" => "core content #1",
        "maininfo" => "url",
    ],[
        "contentid" => 2,
        "artist" => "Artist Name",
        "title" => "Song Title 2",
        "main" => "core content #2",
        "maininfo" => "url",    
    ]
];
```

Then you can turn it into JSON by using your current method:

```
json_encode($songs);
```

Comment: Thank you Steve for spending the time here.  I am concerned that the php side of the house will not work with this method.  The php that is being called it as follows:  include('sample_data.php'); -- sample data includes the data I showed above.  The JSON layouts you provided above are all for JS and are not valid syntax in PHP.  Sorry, not trying to be difficult but having trouble understanding.

Comment: Updated my post to make it clear that I need to store the JSON array in PHP specifically.  The php script pulls it in and then uses $final = array($final_contents);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($final);  --- This is how it is ultimately getting to JSON format.  When getjson.php is called, valid JSON is being returned by the php file.

Comment: Thank you very much @Steve K -- I'm all set now!  Really appreciate your time and efforts.   Thanks to everyone who submitted answers as well--my ajax load or calls were not the problem in the end, I just simply didn't know I couldn't name arrays in JS.  Using a combination of what Steve suggested and changing up the PHP (thanks to another SO user!), I have it working!

Answer (score 0):

You are having array. convert it to json using following code ([json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) and echo so that jquery can receive it:

```
$jsonVar = json_encode($contents);
echo $jsonVar;
```

Update:

Code to call json using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Alternatively you can use shorthand for it:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Of course the file being sent should be in json format, that is:

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

for that you need to convert the array into json.

Comment: Updated question to show I am already retrieving valid JSON.  Please review and let me know if your proposed answer is still viable.  Thanks.

Comment: @KurtW updated answer to point out right reference on jquery side. The code you shared is to use json as callback not converting to json.

Comment: @KurtW I suggest, you just try sending json string instead of php array as I suggested, to know if it works for you.

Comment: It is working as-is.  Sorry, I updated what I posted to reflect that I am using $.ajax({ and not $.json({ -- I got confused a bit when posting and should have copied and pasted.  My data to-be-converted to JSON has to remain to PHP--I cannot change that.  But it is working--for example parse(jsonobj[0][1]['sname']) is returning 'Song Name' just fine.  My challenge is PHP needs to call a named array and JS needs to call it by index. I'm still not clear how to proceed.  Hoping you can help--thanks in advance.